# Using facebook API javascript getting email

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have this method and I want to get the email of a person and Send email=undefined.

First Try:

```
     function testAPI() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
       console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
       FB.api('/me', function(response) {
         console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.email + '.');
         alert('Good to see you, ' + response.email + '.');
       });
     } else {
       console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
     }
   }, {scope:'email'});
```

I was searching and i found that I have to use {scope:image} and if i put it, dont show me the alert

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, that's the correct one:

```
function testAPI() {
    FB.login(
        function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
               console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
               FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                   console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.email + '.');
                   alert('Good to see you, ' + response.email + '.');
               });
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        },
        {scope:'email'}
        );
}
```

where the `{scope:'email'}` is inside the *)* as second argument of the FB.login

Comment: thans now I have the correct method but it doesn´t show me the alert... Any idea?

I have the button of loggin                                    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

Comment: update your question with the entire updated code please.

Comment: Your resetearLocal() are not defined. Anyway, we are going outside the object of your question, it is necessary for you to open a new question otherwise it will create confusion. Please, when you'll check that my answer to the problem of login with facebook is correct flag as correct.

Comment: …and you forgot to close the testAPI function with the closing parenthesis }

Comment: function testAPI() {
    FB.login(function(){
       console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      alert(response.email);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
    }, {'scope':'email'});
  }

Answer (score 24):

Replacing this

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  // ...
```

with this

```
FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,permissions', function(response) {
  console.log(response.name);
  console.log(response.email);
  // ...
```

I can get the user's email.

Comment: Thank you, I did set the permissions but I miss the parameters in the call

Comment: Thanks. Finally found the correct answer for me to get user email.

Answer (score 6):

Or use

```
FB.init('/me', {"fields":"id,name,email,first_name,last_name"}, function(response){
console.log(response.email);
});
```